# issue with DTLpiechart in last version (3.1.9b)

Tags: tikz-pgf, datatool

I have an issue with last version and same code works in version 3.1.5b.

> Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

> datatools version : 2.32

```
$ cat /tmp/fruits.csv 
Name,Quantity
"Apples",30
"Pears",25
"Lemons,Limes",40.5
"Peaches",34.5
"Cherries",20
```

Here the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datapie}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{fruits}{fruits.csv}
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity}{fruits}{\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}

\end{document}
```

This produces :

```
! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...ity}{fruits}{\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a change in tikz. You can no longer give a shift coordinate through a command (I don't know what they changed). datapie will have to adapt its code, e.g. as in the following patch:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\DTLpiechart
 {\begin{scope}[shift={\@dtl@shift}]}
 {\edef\next{\noexpand\begin{scope}[shift={\@dtl@shift}]}\next}
 {}
 {\fail}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{fruits}{fruits.csv}
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity}{fruits}{\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}

\end{document}
```

or like this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\DTLpiechart
 {\begin{scope}[shift={\@dtl@shift}]}
 {\begin{scope}[shift={(\dtl@angle:\dtl@cutlen)}]}
 {}
 {\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{fruits}{fruits.csv}
\DTLpiechart{variable=\quantity}{fruits}{\name=Name,\quantity=Quantity}

\end{document}
```

[image]